# Average $E(u\times u^H)$ where $u$ is uniform on $u^H u= 1$ and $|u^H w| = a$

Tags: complex-analysis, matrix-calculus

Given a vector $w\in \mathcal{C}^{M\times 1}$ and a constant $a$, we can have many vectors $u \in \mathcal{C}^{M\times 1}$, such that $u^H u= 1$ and $|u^H w| = a$. Suppose we have uniform distribution of the unitary $u$, what is the expectation $E(u\times u^H)$ of such $u$ that satisfies the above equations?

I have tried the following method. Let 
$$u= a \times e^{j\theta} \times w + \sum_{i=1}^{M-1} b_j w_j^0$$
where $w_j^0$ is the base vectors if the null space of $w$, and $b_j$ is random variables such that $\sum_{j=1}^{M-1} |b_j|^2=1-a^2$. Therefore, 
\begin{eqnarray}
E(uu^H) &= & a^2 w w^H + \sum_{i=1}^{M-1}E( |b_i|^2 )w_i^0 w_i^{0H} \\
&= & a^2 w w^2 + \frac{1-a^2}{M-1}\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}w_i^0 w_i^{0H} \\
&= & a^2 w w^H + \frac{1-a^2}{M-1} (I - w w^H)\\
&=& \frac{1-a^2}{M-1} I + \frac{M a^2 - 1}{M-1} w w^H
\end{eqnarray}

Please have a look whether it is correct or not. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your notation, is $\mathcal C^{M\times 1}$ the space of $M-$dimensional vectors over the complex numbers?

Comment: @DanRobertson Yes. It is a complex space of $M$ dimensional vectors.

Comment: So the space of normal vectors $u$ is a $(2M-1)-$sphere and the space of normal $u$ such that $|\langle u,w\rangle |=a$ is a $2(M-1)-$sphere. The tedious bit is then to write down the distribution for vectors in this space and then work out the covariance. You should be able to construct a matrix $P$ depending on $a,w$ to convert the general problem into one where e.g. $a=1$ and $u=e_1$ (and likely special cases when $a=0$ or $u=0$ if you care about them) then you can use $P$ to translate the covariance matrix back to the original problem.

Comment: You should probably update the question to say what you have already tried.

Comment: @DanRobertson Thank you so much. Actually this is not my homework. I found that some of my work can be summarized to such a problem. What I need is some of the keywords that I can go into deeper of that area. Thanks again.